(Scheme) Having trouble with binary search tree in-order traversal
I'm trying to write a Scheme program that performs an in-order traversal of a binary search tree:
(define (inorder lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst)
     '())
    ((not (pair? lst))
          (list lst))
    (else 
     (append (inorder (car lst))
             (list (car (cdr lst)))
             (inorder (cdr (cdr lst)))))))

(define tree-a '((a . b) . (c . (d . e))))
(inorder tree-a)

The issue is, I keep getting the error:
car: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: b 


I know what the issue is, (list (car (cdr lst))) has issues if the given value isn't a pair, but I don't know how to fix it.

'((a . b) . (c . (d . e))) is more normally written as '((a . b) c d . e), which I doubt is what you want as I can't figure out how that's supposed to represent a binary tree.

I'd start by using a struct to represent nodes of the tree, but if you're expected to use lists for some reason, at least write accessor functions with decent names instead of sprinkling car and cdr everywhere, so it's easier to read and follow. (See this answer of mine to another question for an example)

If I understand correctly, this is a binary tree, with only leaves (no symbols on nodes, other than leaves). You code that tree with pairs, a leaf being a symbol ('a 'b 'c...), and a node begin a pair (left . right). Is that correct?

@chrslg The tree was given as test code, where an in-order traversal should give the output of (a b c d e)

Why are you traversing (car (cdr lst)) instead of just (cdr lst)? This is a tree, it's not a linear list, so you should treat the car and cdr equivalently.

Yeah, but my question is: is it this tree?

Consider the simplest case, (inorder '(a . b)). That should produce recursive calls (inorder 'a) and (inorder 'b)

@Barmar asked my followup question (if you answer "yes" to the last one): then why expecting to find a (cadr lst) and a (cddr lst)? A tree is either a leaf (you treated that case in the (not (pair? lst)) condition), or a pair of subtrees, and then all you have to do is to recursively call your function on (car lst) and (cdr lst). Btw lst is not a very good name for that variable, since it is not a list.

The reason for the error is, as OP surmised, that it is an error to call car or cdr on anything that is not a pair. This situation occurs in two lines of code:
;;...
(list (car (cdr lst)))
(inorder (cdr (cdr lst)))
;;...

It is unclear why OP believes that cdr should be called on lst before calling car and cdr here, and also unclear why the line (list (car (cdr lst))) is needed at all. Simply removing this superfluous code fixes the problem:
(define (inorder-fixed lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((not (pair? lst))
         (list lst))
        (else 
         (append (inorder-fixed (car lst))
                 (inorder-fixed (cdr lst))))))

A tree is either empty (the base case), or it is a pair of subtrees, or it is a leaf. Given a pair of subtrees, the car of the pair is the left subtree, and the cdr of the pair is the right subtree. Dotted pairs are a convenient representation here due to symmetry. Recall that (cdr '(a . b)) yields b, while (cdr '(a b)) yields (b). But (car '(a . b)) and (car '(a b)) both yield a; the asymmetry of the proper list representation under car and cdr requires slightly more care, i.e., would require cadr to extract the right subtree.
I would suggest organizing this code slightly differently for clarity. This can be expressed more clearly by testing for a pair? directly instead of testing for the negation of this test:
(define (in-order tree)
  (cond ((null? tree) '())
        ((pair? tree)
         (append (in-order (car tree))
                 (in-order (cdr tree))))
        (else (list tree))))

When the input tree is empty an empty list is returned. When the input tree is a pair of subtrees the results of traversing each subtree in order are appended together and returned. When the input tree is simply a leaf a list containing that leaf is returned.
Here is a sample interaction:
in-order.rkt> (define tree-a '((a . b) . (c . (d . e))))
in-order.rkt> (inorder-fixed tree-a)
'(a b c d e)
in-order.rkt> (in-order tree-a)
'(a b c d e)

